# Updating the score based on the number attempts of the player

Tags: bash, shell

good morning guys i kinda faced this probelem when i was working on this project earlier ,and it goes like this :
I need to change the score of player in this game and it depenent on the tries that the player make if he guessed write in the first try he gets 3 point and 2 for the second and 1 for the lash try ,for a clear view this is how my code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

tentative=3
cpt=0
score=0

echo "Votre nombre de tentative est 3"
cut -d: -f3 Facile.txt       
MotCorrect=$(cut -d: -f2 Facile.txt )        
while [ $cpt -lt 3 ] 
                do         
                        echo "QuiSuisJe?"
                        read QuiSuisJe
                    `enter code here`cpt=`expr $cpt + 1`

                    if [ $QuiSuisJe == $MotCorrect ]                       
                        then
                        echo "Correct"
                        cptScore=`expr $cptScore+3`
                         score=$((score+3))
                        echo "$score"
                break                 
                    else
                     tentative=`expr $tentative - $cpt`
                    echo "Votre reponse n'est pas Correct."
                    fi


            done
```

Comment: What is the relation with `ssh`?

Comment: i just made a tag mistake bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function "amount of tries" -> "score" you describe is `score(tries) = 4 - tries` :

```
tries    score    4 - tries
  1        3          3  
  2        2          2
  3        1          1
```

Your current code maintains the amount of tries in the `$cpt` var, so I would derive the score from that variable :

```
score=$(( 4 - cpt ))
```

As a side-note, it seems like you're misusing the `$tentative` variable. From what I can tell, it should describe the maximum amount of tries, and in that case :

- it shouldn't be updated in your else block ; whether you fail or not, the maximum amount of tries remains the same (it's the current amount of tries that changes, but you've handled that with `$cpt` outside of the if/else)
- it should be used in two places : in the first `echo` which outputs how many tries the user have, and in the `while`'s condition which tests whether the user has reached the maximum amount of tries yet.

Comment: thank you,sir i did exaclty what you just mentioned and it's  totally working  fine.